# Disadvantages of making all TypeScript in a project using React with .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was writing TypeScript + React (JSX) code, but sometimes I accidentally wrote JSX with the extension of `.ts` and got into trouble. Of course, if the extension is set to `.tsx`, the solution will be resolved, but is there any inconvenience if all files are set to `.tsx` from the beginning regardless of the presence or absence of JSX?

If all files are made with `.tsx,`

> " `.ts` has an extension conflict with MPEG-2 TS, but `.tsx` does not."
>
> "Even if you need JSX later, you can write as it is, no need to change the file name."

Advantages such as can be expected.

I know that

> Cannot cast  format.

but besides that I hope you can tell me if there is something like that.

> A `.tsx` file has such inconveniences.

***What I checked***

- [Allow JSX without using `.tsx` extension](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30503) - Conversely, suggest that you can write JSX in .ts (closed)
- There are two types of cast notation: `value as type` and `<type> value`, and the latter cannot be written in a `.tsx` file

***Environment***

- TypeScript 3.7.5
- React 16.12
- Webpack 4.41.6 Use `ts-loader` to load to Webpack (type check is thrown to `fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin`)
- Editor uses Visual Studio Code

Comment: But isn’t the extension  conflict something you should solve on your pc? It seems weird to adjust your code just because your pc associates TS with MPEG...

Comment: For me the issue are generic, For example I cannot use generic for arrow functions, I need to make them standard function to use such in tsx.

Answer (score 0):

There is no significant drawback to using `.tsx` everywhere.

The *only* thing you can't do in `.tsx` files is a small syntax difference.

You can't use `<foo>` to cast.

For example, instead of:

```
<any>foo
```

you must write:

```
 foo as any
```

If you use the first syntax in a `.tsx` file it will be obvious and easy to correct.

Comment: Not only. Generics can be a problem as well

Comment: @AlekseyL. do you have an example? or link?

Comment: `const foo = <T>(t: T) => t;`

Comment: Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGcsII4BeOAHgBUA+AChgBccTgEpW3ODFJA